# Force redirect from HTTP to HTTPS via htaccess with multisite installation

Tags: craft3, redirect, htaccess, https, ssl

I'm using Craft CMS 3 multisite installation with more than 20 website based on subdomains.
There are websites:

```
website.com
one.website.com
two.website.com
```

with identical url paths but different content.
I need to redirect each website from `http` to `https`.
Root website htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

</IfModule>
```

But this adds `index.php` to URL while redirects. So `http://one.website.com/test` become into `https://one.website.com/index.php?p=test`

Answer (score 1):

move these lines

```
 RewriteEngine On
# Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

to the end of the file

Comment: it works but it doesn't helps to redirect subdomains to its https versions. I guess there are should be some wildcard in RewriteCond row to redirect all subdomains.